# iterate over 2 arrays in PHP to display items with same account id

Tags: php, loops

I have two classes containing informations about accounts and invoices like this

The accounts list

```
array (
  0 => 
     'id' => 1,
     'username' => 'abc',
     'company' => 'My Corporation',
  )),
  1 => 
 'id' => 2,
     'username' => 'cde',
     'company' => 'My Company',
  ))
```

The invoice list

```
array (
  0 => 
     'account_id' => 1,
     'invoiceId' => '15',
  )),
  1 => 
 'id' => 2,
     'account_id' => '2',
     'invoiceId' => '17',
  )),
  2 => 
     'account_id' => 1,
     'invoiceId' => '20',
  )),
  3 => 
 'id' => 2,
     'account_id' => '2',
     'invoiceId' => '30',
  ))
```

When iterating over both collections each invoice to be shown once. My issues is that everything will be duplicated

My code is

```
<?php
 
   foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
       foreach($accounts as $account) {
          echo $account->getUsername($invoice->getAccountId())."<BR>";
          echo $account->getCompany($invoice->getAccountId());

        }
     }
```

I am not sure what I should do

Comment: Please update your question to show how you want the output set out? I don't follow exactly what you're trying to show here. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to achieve here, but you might consider iterating accounts first then invoices. Then it will show all accounts with every invoice, if you set a condition to only show the invoice if the `account_id` matches.

Comment: you are using methods of presumably an Account class that u have not provided the code for.

Comment: @A.Rahimi I understand, as I said I am using a class, methods in there are pretty basic getter and setter for id or username. I do not think they are needed for the answer, but sure its always better to have full information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this sould solve tour problem:

```
    <?php
 
$accounts = array (
  0 => array (
     'id' => 1,
     'username' => 'abc',
     'company' => 'My Corporation',
  ),
  1 => array (
      'id' => 2,
     'username' => 'cde',
     'company' => 'My Company',
  ));

$invoices = array (
  0 => array (
     'account_id' => 1,
     'invoiceId' => '15',
  ),
  1 => array (
      'id' => 2,
     'account_id' => '2',
     'invoiceId' => '17',
  ),
  2 => array (
     'account_id' => 1,
     'invoiceId' => '20',
  ),
  3 => array (
      'id' => 2,
     'account_id' => '2',
     'invoiceId' => '30',
  ));

foreach($accounts as $account) {
   foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
         echo "account id : ";
         echo $account['id'];
         echo "invoices: ";
         if ( $invoice['account_id'] === $account['id'] ) {

            echo $invoice['account_id'];
             // echo $account->getUsername($invoice->getAccountId())."<BR>";
            // echo $account->getCompany($invoice->getAccountId());
            
         }
         
        }
     }
```

Comment: Yes thanks for the help, this works. I realize that I tried this but as I didn't wrapped je html inside of the if it wasn't working, obviously...